# MySQL Error : Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1242

Getting error : `#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row`

while executing this

```
SELECT `Index` , `FundName` ,Count(*), 
    (SELECT COALESCE(sum(b.PricePerWeek),0) 
     FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions
     WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= SubscribeDt  
     GROUP BY FundIDSend)

FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions b, tbl_FundStatic a

WHERE a.FundID = b.FundIDSend

AND FundIDSend IN 
    (SELECT FundID
     FROM tbl_FundStatic
     WHERE UserID = '14')

GROUP BY a.FundName,a.Index
```

What could be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: the sub query (select COALESCE(sum(b.PricePerWeek),0) FROM tbl_FundSubscriptions

 Where DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= SubscribeDt  group by FundIDSend)
 return more than one , you put the sub query in the field list

Comment: The sub-query (`select COALESCE...`) is returning more than one row for each row in the result set, which it may not.

Comment: If that is the case, What could be the right Query to do this?

Comment: The right query to do what exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the query you're looking for?  Not knowing your table structure, we'll never know, but this does what your query appears to have been indented to do.  (Does that make any sense at all?)

```
SELECT `Index`, `FundName`, COUNT(*), 
    (SELECT SUM(`PricePerWeek`)
     FROM `tbl_FundSubscriptions`
     WHERE DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= `SubscribeDt` 
           AND `FundIDSend` = `tbl_FundStatic`.`FundID`)

FROM `tbl_FundStatic`

WHERE `UserID` = '14'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery is returning more then 1 row.

Either you `LIMIT` the subquery to one row or you `LEFT JOIN` it with the other table.

Comment: If that is the case, What could be the right Query to do this?

Comment: Thanks but how could I left join and get the desired result.